# Setup private dynamic DNS

Tags: nginx, bind, dyndns

I'd like to setup my own dynamic DNS server on a VPS running Ubuntu. Nginx is installed and a domain connected. The ideal result would be to create a subdomain and have that handle the dynamic DNS part, so that a simple ping is redirected to the IP the subdomain points to. I believe that would be an A Record that I need to set for that, right? Is that possible in Nginx? Or do I have to do that with Bind?

I already searched for stepwise tutorials, but haven't found anything useful for Nginx. I'm also kind of on an entry level in Nginx and also in Bind.

Is there an easy way to create a dynamic DNS server with Nginx?

Comment: You're looking at BIND, not nginx for what you want to do.

Comment: bind9 is what you want

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. So I assume that I have to set the subdomain with Nginx and then the IP deviation with Bind9, right? Any good stepwise tutorial for that? I'm having a bit of a hard time finding one.